# Problema al compliar un .py

Tags: python, tkinter

Cuando  compilo un programa que estoy haciendo, usando tkinter para la interfaz grafica, meda el siguente error:

```
  File "Main.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\raulc\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI142122\Scripts\BarraDeProgresion.py", line 2, in <module>
    from tkinter import HORIZONTAL
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'
```

Alguien sabe como solucionarlo, gracias de antemano.

Comment: @MarcosGuerrero El OP nunca dijo que tuviera problemas para ejecutar su programa sin compilar (lo que le habría pasado si no tuviera el modulo instalado).

Comment: Que estás usando para crear el exe?

Comment: @Dante S auto-py-to-exe. Es lo que uso para compilarlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Hay que configurarlo en "Advanced > --hidden-import" según la [documentación](https://nitratine.net/blog/post/issues-when-using-auto-py-to-exe/?utm_source=auto_py_to_exe&utm_medium=readme_link&utm_campaign=auto_py_to_exe_help).

Sección de la documentación, bueno en realidad es el blog del autor (Traducida):

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named x / ImportError: No module named
> x Esto significa que un módulo en particular (En este caso `x`) no ha
> sido agregado al paquete. He visto que esto ocurra con paquetes en la
> librería de `pandas` y `win32api`; mientras identifiques el paquete
> (Por ejemplo `x`), entonces es muy fácil de arreglar.
>
> Para arreglarlo desde la IU, abre la pestaña de "Avanzado" (Advanced)
> y busca la entrada `--hidden-import`. Simplemente escribe el nombre
> del módulo en esta entrada. Si el error original sigue apareciendo, lo
> más probable es que hayas hecho este paso mal.
>
> Otra alternativa en caso de que utilices muchas versiones de Python es
> que hayas instalado tu paquete en diferente versión de la que se se
> utilizó para instalar `auto-py-to-exe`.

[image: Configuración]